# How to display 5 columns per row in Opencart?

Tags: opencart2.x

How to display 5 columns per row in opencart?

What I have tried is Extensions -> Modules ->Featured then edit the module. I have changed the limit to 5 and decreased the width and height but after changing it displays the same. I am not able to get five columns per row. Please suggest me how to acheve it.

Thank you.

Comment: I am using the Opencart version 2.1.0.1

Comment: You have changed the product limit show in home page. In admin, there is no option to change row limit. For this you have to add custom css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my popular.tpl file in catalog/view/theme/promoglasses/template/module

```html
<div class="tab-title">
<h2>Popular Products</h2>
<ul class="tabs tabs-popular-products tab_categorys">
<li class="active" rel="tab129-popular-products">POPULAR Products</li>
</ul>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />

<div class="row">
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
  <div class="product-layout col-sm-5ths">
    <div class="product-thumb transition">
      <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
        <div class="label-cont"> As low as </div>
        <div class="label-price">
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <p class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
         
          <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <?php } ?>
        
        </div>
        <div class="label-sup">
        <b>
          <sup>(C)</sup>
        </b>
        </div>
        <br />
        <p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating">
          <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if ($product['rating'] < $i) { ?>
          <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

For the CSS part here I have written the code for class col-sm-5ths:

```css
.col-sm-5ths {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 1px;
    position: relative;
}
```